# Flutter how to use setState or something in class

Tags: flutter, dart

Flutter state isnt changing from class. I am taking boolean value from class but issue is its not changing. I need to refresh or save screen then i can see changes.

My code

```
class _PlayerScreenState extends State<PlayerScreen> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    context.read<PlayerProvider>().link = widget.episode.contentUrl;
    context.read<PlayerProvider>().playerLength = widget.episode.duration;
    context.read<PlayerProvider>().episodeName = widget.episode.title;
    context.read<PlayerProvider>().episodeThumbnail =
        widget.podcastInfo.artworkUrl100;
    context.read<PlayerProvider>().episode = widget.episode;
    context.read<PlayerProvider>().podcastInfo = widget.podcastInfo;
    if (widget.startAgain) context.read<PlayerProvider>().play();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BaseScreen(
      //Dont show Bottom Nav Bar
      showNavbar: false,
      child: Consumer<PlayerProvider>(
        builder: (context, model, child) {
          // model.link = widget.episode.contentUrl;
          // model.playerLength = widget.episode.duration;
          // model.play();
          return Container(
            child: Column(
              children: [

                //Player Controls
                Container(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(40, 15, 40, 10),
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    color: Colors.black,
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                        topRight: Radius.circular(20),
                        topLeft: Radius.circular(20)),
                  ),
                  height: 160,
                  child: Column(
                    children: [
                      //Progree bar
                      Row(
                        children: [
                          //current time
                          Text(
                            // "01:27",
                            model.playerTimeNow.inMinutes.toString() +
                                ":" +
                                (model.playerTimeNow.inSeconds % 60).toString(),
                            style: TextStyle(
                              fontSize: 13,
                              color: Colors.white,
                            ),
                          ),

                          //Slider
                          Expanded(
                            child: Slider(
                              activeColor: Color(0xffe7ad29),
                              inactiveColor: Color(0xFF707070),
                              value: model.playerBarValue,
                              onChanged: (val) {
                                model.seekFromBar(val);
                              },
                            ),
                          ),

                          //Remaining time
                          Text(
                            model.playerLength.inMinutes.toString() +
                                ":" +
                                (model.playerLength.inSeconds % 60).toString(),
                            style: TextStyle(
                              fontSize: 13,
                              color: Colors.white,
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),

                      Container(
                        child: Expanded(
                          child: Row(
                            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                            children: [

                              IconButton(
                                iconSize: 70,
                                icon: Container(
                                  width: 70,
                                  height: 70,
                                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                                      Radius.circular(70),
                                    ),
                                    border: Border.all(
                                      color: Color(0xffe7ad29),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                  child: Icon(
                                    model.isPlaying
                                        ? Icons.pause
                                        : Icons.play_arrow,
                                    color: Colors.white,
                                    size: 40,
                                  ),
                                ),
                                onPressed: () {
                                  if (model.isPlaying) {
                                    model.pause();
                                    print("Paused");
                                  } else {
                                    model.resume();
                                    print("Played");
                                  }
                                },
                              ),
                              //Next Button

                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

you can see i am showing pause if isPlaying is true and if false other icon.

and its coming from another class

```
class PlayerProvider extends ChangeNotifier {
  final player = AssetsAudioPlayer();
  String link;
  Duration playerTimeNow = Duration(seconds: 0);
  Duration playerLength;
  double playerBarValue = 0.0;
  Episode episode;
  Item podcastInfo;

  String episodeName, episodeThumbnail;

  bool isPlaying = false;

  PlayerProvider() {
    updateState();
  }

  play() async {
    print("Started Playing");
    // Stop previous playing
    player.stop();
    playerTimeNow = Duration(seconds: 0);
    isPlaying = false;

    // link = updateLinkToHttps(link);
    print(link);
    final audio = Audio.network(
      link,
      metas: Metas(
        title: podcastInfo.collectionName,
        artist: podcastInfo.artistName,
        album: podcastInfo.trackName,
        image: MetasImage.network(
            podcastInfo.artworkUrl600), //can be MetasImage.network
      ),
    );

    var duration = await player.open(
      audio,
      showNotification: true,
      notificationSettings: NotificationSettings(),
    );
    isPlaying = true;

    // player.play(); // Usually you don't want to wait for playback to finish.
    print("started");
  }

  pause() async {
    await player.pause();
    isPlaying = false;
    print("paused");
  }

  resume() async {
    //TODO: Setup resume
    await player.seek(playerTimeNow);
    player.play();
    isPlaying = true;
  }

  speed(double val) async {
    print(val);
    //TODO: Setup resume
    await player.forwardOrRewind(val);
    isPlaying = true;
  }

  updateState() {
    player.currentPosition.listen((event) {
      playerTimeNow = event;
      updatePlayerBar();
    });
  }

  updatePlayerBar() {
    int totalLengthInMilliSeconds = playerLength.inMilliseconds;
    int totalPlayedInMilliSeconds = playerTimeNow.inMilliseconds;
    double newPlayerBarValue =
        totalPlayedInMilliSeconds / totalLengthInMilliSeconds;
    playerBarValue = newPlayerBarValue;
    notifyListeners();
  }

  forward() async {
    //TODO: Check if at-least 10 seconds are left;
    if (playerTimeNow + Duration(seconds: 10) < playerLength)
      await player.seek(playerTimeNow + Duration(seconds: 10));
    else
      await player.seek(playerLength);
    print("Forwarded 10 seconds");
  }

  backword() async {
    Duration back = playerTimeNow.inSeconds > 10
        ? playerTimeNow - Duration(seconds: 10)
        : Duration(seconds: 0);
    await player.seek(back);
    print("Backwarded 10 seconds");
  }

  seekFromBar(double val) async {
    double totalMillis = playerLength.inMilliseconds * val;
    int newMillis = totalMillis.toInt();
    Duration newSeekLocations = Duration(milliseconds: newMillis);
    await player.seek(newSeekLocations);
    print("Seek from Bar");
  }

  setState() {
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

Its also working but state isnt changing i think and i try to use setState but i think i cant use in class. So how can i change the state ? If i save my code or refresh the page then i can see boolean value is changing but i need to change on page i cant refresh.

Comment: You need to call `notifyListeners` in each function of `PlayerProvider` where you wish to update the state of the underlying Consumer.

Comment: @Vineet updated my code i am calling PlayerProider already can you check >

Comment: It doesn't work like that. Call `notifyListeners` in the pause and resume functions of the provider class.

Comment: Also you need to wrap all the consumer widgets in `ChangeNotifierProvider`. [Reference](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/state-mgmt/simple)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to call the provider in your widget whenever notifyListner run it will change the state

```
final provider = Provider.of<PlayerProvider>(context);
```